# Heroku Error, I didn't understand that is this error related to npm packages or with timeout

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, deployment

I am trying to deploy my express app on Heroku, but it is crashing every time with following logs: -

```
2019-03-22T19:26:26.149208+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-03-22T19:26:26.122569+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2019-03-22T19:26:25.977206+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-03-22T19:26:25.977226+00:00 app[web.1]: > Server@1.0.0 start /app
2019-03-22T19:26:25.977228+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2019-03-22T19:26:25.977229+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-03-22T19:26:26.059671+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:584
2019-03-22T19:26:26.059674+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2019-03-22T19:26:26.059676+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2019-03-22T19:26:26.059678+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-03-22T19:26:26.059680+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '/app/server.js'
2019-03-22T19:26:26.059682+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582:15)
2019-03-22T19:26:26.059683+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:508:25)
2019-03-22T19:26:26.059685+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:754:12)
2019-03-22T19:26:26.059687+00:00 app[web.1]: at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
2019-03-22T19:26:26.059689+00:00 app[web.1]: at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
2019-03-22T19:26:26.065404+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2019-03-22T19:26:26.065766+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2019-03-22T19:26:26.066805+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Server@1.0.0 start: `node server.js`
2019-03-22T19:26:26.066916+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2019-03-22T19:26:26.067117+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2019-03-22T19:26:26.067233+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the Server@1.0.0 start script.
2019-03-22T19:26:26.067395+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2019-03-22T19:26:26.071997+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-03-22T19:26:26.072138+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2019-03-22T19:26:26.072224+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2019-03-22T19_26_26_068Z-debug.log
2019-03-22T19:27:18.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user ab98647@gmail.com
2019-03-22T19:27:32.768091+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-03-22T19:27:34.827273+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2019-03-22T19:27:32.578293+00:00 app[api]: Release v13 created by user ab98647@gmail.com
2019-03-22T19:27:32.578293+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 7e0d91c1 by user ab98647@gmail.com
2019-03-22T19:27:33.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2019-03-22T19:27:36.739160+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-03-22T19:27:36.739182+00:00 app[web.1]: > Server@1.0.0 start /app
2019-03-22T19:27:36.739184+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2019-03-22T19:27:36.739185+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-03-22T19:27:37.087619+00:00 app[web.1]: App is working
2019-03-22T19:27:37.617321+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2019-03-22T19:30:44.261549+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/" host=secret-beach-23042.herokuapp.com request_id=3a765852-d9f6-492b-869e-8e6f6f57cdf7 fwd="47.247.184.33" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2019-03-22T19:31:23.585873+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/" host=secret-beach-23042.herokuapp.com request_id=3c116fc4-4d3f-4b55-ad9f-97942e9e9e99 fwd="47.247.184.33" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30003ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2019-03-22T19:38:19.581701+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/" host=secret-beach-23042.herokuapp.com request_id=3a9756f6-0c75-419e-9724-b76da81b853b fwd="47.247.184.33" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2019-03-22T20:01:13.086387+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2019-03-22T20:01:13.091324+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2019-03-22T20:01:14.577272+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2019-03-22T20:01:14.691025+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2019-03-22T20:41:21.048924+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2019-03-22T20:41:23.311286+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2019-03-22T20:41:25.122476+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-03-22T20:41:25.122494+00:00 app[web.1]: > Server@1.0.0 start /app
2019-03-22T20:41:25.122496+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2019-03-22T20:41:25.122498+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-03-22T20:41:25.655023+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2019-03-22T20:41:25.452310+00:00 app[web.1]: App is working
2019-03-22T20:46:58.094883+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/" host=secret-beach-23042.herokuapp.com request_id=592a14a7-b683-4f5a-9593-ed0eca3d1c7e fwd="47.247.184.33" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2019-03-22T20:50:12.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user ab98647@gmail.com
2019-03-22T20:50:27.551012+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 58e9e00f by user ab98647@gmail.com
2019-03-22T20:50:27.551012+00:00 app[api]: Release v14 created by user ab98647@gmail.com
2019-03-22T20:50:28.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2019-03-22T20:50:31.597374+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2019-03-22T20:50:31.619924+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2019-03-22T20:50:32.995500+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2019-03-22T20:50:32.995500+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2019-03-22T20:50:34.030210+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2019-03-22T20:50:37.589947+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-03-22T20:50:37.589988+00:00 app[web.1]: > Server@1.0.0 start /app
2019-03-22T20:50:37.589990+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2019-03-22T20:50:37.589992+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-03-22T20:50:38.620173+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2019-03-22T20:50:38.544170+00:00 app[web.1]: App is working
2019-03-22T20:56:30.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user ab98647@gmail.com
2019-03-22T20:56:45.960310+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2019-03-22T20:56:45.978197+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2019-03-22T20:56:45.647303+00:00 app[api]: Release v15 created by user ab98647@gmail.com
2019-03-22T20:56:45.647303+00:00 app[api]: Deploy f2758b5c by user ab98647@gmail.com
2019-03-22T20:56:46.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2019-03-22T20:56:47.541219+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2019-03-22T20:56:47.659446+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2019-03-22T20:56:48.601100+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2019-03-22T20:56:50.396013+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-03-22T20:56:50.396063+00:00 app[web.1]: > Server@1.0.0 start /app
2019-03-22T20:56:50.396065+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2019-03-22T20:56:50.396067+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-03-22T20:56:50.845287+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2019-03-22T20:56:50.782758+00:00 app[web.1]: App is working
2019-03-22T21:31:11.982402+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2019-03-22T21:31:11.992917+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2019-03-22T21:31:12.708220+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2019-03-22T21:31:12.769110+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2019-03-23T06:27:23.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user ab98647@gmail.com
2019-03-23T06:27:39.496098+00:00 app[api]: Release v16 created by user ab98647@gmail.com
2019-03-23T06:27:39.496098+00:00 app[api]: Deploy fbae53e0 by user ab98647@gmail.com
2019-03-23T06:27:40.388432+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2019-03-23T06:27:43.640584+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2019-03-23T06:27:40.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2019-03-23T06:27:46.450974+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-03-23T06:27:46.450990+00:00 app[web.1]: > Server@1.0.0 start /app
2019-03-23T06:27:46.450992+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2019-03-23T06:27:46.450994+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-03-23T06:27:46.969621+00:00 app[web.1]: App is working
2019-03-23T06:27:47.560758+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
```

Here even after build succeeded app crashed, why is it so and I can't understand the error like is it related to npm or timeout or something else ?
The Procfile contains : web: node server.js

Here is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "Server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "server.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt-nodejs": "0.0.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "knex": "^0.16.3",
    "mysql": "^2.16.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.18.9"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/ankit986/Brainly-React-Project/tree/master/Backend/Backend/Server"
  },
  "description": ""
}
```

and the server.js file is:-

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
const cors = require('cors');
const knex = require('knex')


const mysql = knex({
  client: 'mysql',
  connection: {
    host : '127.0.0.1',
    user : 'root',
    password : 'Amit',
    database : 'brainly'
  }
});

const app = express();

const Signin = require('./SigninServer.js');
const Register = require('./RegisterServer.js');
const Profile = require('./ProfileServer.js');
const Image = require('./ImageServer.js');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

app.get('/',(req, res) => {
    res.send("working");
})

app.post('/signin', (req, res) => {Signin.handleSignin(req, res, mysql, bcrypt)})
app.post('/register', (req, res) => {Register.handleRegister(req, res, mysql, bcrypt)})
app.get('/profile/:id',(req, res) => {Profile.handleProfile(req, res, mysql, bcrypt)})
app.put('/image', (req, res) => {Image.handleImage(req, res, mysql, bcrypt)})

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, ()=>{
    console.log("App is working");
}) ;
```

Comment: Please show us `server.js`.

Comment: okay I added to the main post

Comment: By the way It is working on local host

Comment: It looks like you're stopping the service yourself. What do you see when you visit your site? (As an aside, your MySQL configuration won't work like that. It definitely won't be running on `localhost`, but the exact details will depend on the addon you choose to use.)

Comment: No, it is running perfectly on my local host

Comment: That's not what I'm saying. On _Heroku_ your database definitely won't work like that. Again, _whatdo you see when you visit your site?_